# Compilation error while evaluating java stream expression in IntelliJ Idea 2020.1.4

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea-2020

I am using latest IntelliJ Idea ultimate version 2020.1.4 and trying to debug my unit tests. My unit test is run as gradle test. When I evaluate a java method which returns a List , I can see all the values in the list but the moment I try to access the stream() and use filter in the evaluation window I get compilation error.

Just evaluating list.stream() seems to work but adding filter has got some issues.
[image]

This is when I use .stream() on my list.
[image]
And thats the error I get
[image]

This used to work in the older version of idea.Any pointers what can be the reason ?

Comment: `getListValues()` seems to not be found? And that has nothing to do with streams?

Comment: That's what I find strange.if I evaluate just list it gives me correct values. But if I evaluate list.stream().filter(somefilter condition using -> operator), I get method not found error.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre], currently as it stands your question is unanswerable, there is *not* enough information, so please [edit] your question with a real example, one which you expect to work, but doesn't

Comment: @Lino-Votedon'tsayThanks I have edited my post with screen captures from real debug. Hope this explains the problem better.

Comment: I assume that the debugger has problems when resolving the inferred types. What you can do is assiting the debugger with "type hints" e.g: `.filter((ValidDocumentTransactionNotification vdtn) -> your_condition)` and also by using a terminating operation. I've experienced similar errors where IntelliJ would mark a complete unaffected piece of code as an error even though the problem was somewhere else

Comment: Also if you can't find anymore information I suggest having a look at the [Jetbrains Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/)  and if you still find nothing there, feel free to open up a Bug

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Linobut unfortunately it didn't work as ValidDocumentTransactionNotification is not a functional interface. My compilation error mentioned this.